# AFNetworking 2.0 - use responseObject as NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

this is the [recommended way](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#get-request) to send `GET` request in AFNetworking 2.0. I want to get the value of a specific key in the json, so I want to use `responseObject` as `NSDictionary`. this is what I was trying:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

it didn't work:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa048120'
```

how can I get the value of a specific key in `responseObject`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` sets `responseSerializer` to an `AFJSONResponseSerializer` instance, so `responseObject` already is your parsed JSON (in your case, it'll be an `NSDictionary` according to what you said).

Then, just use it as you'd use a dictionary:

```
NSString *value = responseObject[@"someKey"];
```

Comment: I had a similar problem using AFNetworking. I get a parsed JSON object back and need to store it in an array for later use. Is the parsed JSON a dictionary with strings as values? I can't seem to use KVC to get into the dictionary though

Answer (score 5):

The response object is already a dictionary! AFNetworking did handle that for you.