# When I convert NSData to NSDictionary,there showed something different on iOS9 and iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: on ios9]

[image: on ios8]

On iOS 9 the result is what I want,however,on iOS 8,the dictionary is not a real dictionary.The two pictures is on iOS 9 and iOS 8.What's more,on iOS 10,it's fine.

I wonder how can I convert `NSData` to `NSDictionary` correctly on iOS 8.

I use `AFHTTPClient` to get data.

Comment: Please print the value of jsonObject, and see the difference.

Comment: Your two pictures do not show that it is not a real dictionary, just that the debugger is showing them differently. What do methods such as `class`, `isKindOfClass:` etc. tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response object is already a dictionary! AFNetworking did handle that for you .

print the log of responseObject which you getting from response :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19086685/3901620

Comment: The response object is `NSData` not a dictionary.I'm sure.